# Why http get attr [params] needs to be {[param: string]: string | string[]}?

Tags: angular, angular11

## Problem desc

this.http.get() shout an error in type inference

```
error TS2322: Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IInfo[]>'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is missing the following properties from type 'IInfo[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more.
```

Here is the code below:

```js
// type declaration
export interface IQueryParams {
    startTime: number;
    endTime: number;
    orderType: string;
}

export interface IInfo {
    name: string;
}

// inside the service
getInfo(queryDataParams: IQueryParams): Observable<IInfo[]> {
        return this.http.get<IInfo[]>(`xxx.com`, {
        params: queryDataParams
    });
}
```

## Analysis

I find out it's the params' type problem. In Angular's declaration, the params object needs to be `HttpParams | {[param: string]: string | string[]}` , but i send it a `{[param: string]: number}`

Maybe typescript cannot find the best declaration, so it use the first one

## Solve

I can solve the problem by parse the params obj to an HttpParams type obj or set the params as any, both works

```
// tool function
function generateHttpParams(params: Object): HttpParams; // parse obj to HttpParams


// parse to HttpParams
getInfo(queryDataParams: IQueryParams): Observable<IInfo[]> {
        return this.http.get<IInfo[]>(`xxx.com`, {
        params: generateHttpParams(queryDataParams)
    });
}

// set as any
getInfo(queryDataParams: IQueryParams): Observable<IInfo[]> {
        return this.http.get<IInfo[]>(`xxx.com`, {
        params: queryDataParams as any
    });
}
```

---

But i think maybe it's more appropriate to turn `{[param: string]: string | string[]}` into `{[param: string]: any}` in get type declaration

Answer (score 1):

A pattern I often use when dealing with request parameters is:

```js
yourServiceMethod(requestParams: YourInterface): Observable<YourResponseType> {

  let params = new HttpParams();
  Object.keys(requestParams).forEach(key => params = params.append(key, requestParams[key]));

  return this.httpClient
             .get<YourResponseType>(this.baseUrl, { params })
             .pipe(
               map(response => response),
               catchError(() => of(null)),
             );  
}
```

Of course, you can create a shared function to do this conversion from an object into HttpParams. At the end of the day, these values have to be converted to strings to be passed through the query string, hence the interface requirement from Angular.

Comment: yeah, it's my func `generateHttpParams` 's work~

Comment: Thx for sharing, i think angular may use any is more appropriate or not?

Comment: Cool. I saw that in your code, but not the implementation.

Comment: I will only use `any` in rare circumstances. Often it's more appropriate to type something as `unknown` if you truly don't know the type, and then cast to another interface or type. Using `any` is setting yourself up for trouble in my opinion.

Comment: Oh i seee, i add the tips in question.

Comment: Yeah, but i actually know the type of my params, but the get ts type can not refer to it... I think that's the real problem~

Comment: No matter what your interface looks like, you can only pass strings as params in the query string. To keep your code DRY, you can always use a utility type to Pick<> or Omit<> fields from an existing type, but I find just using an interface with dynamic keys is sufficient.